# Replacing a tag value in XML using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, shell, sed, xmlstarlet

I am trying to replace the value `test` with `lookup` in input.xml. The script is executing without any error but it is not replacing the value.

```
sed -i '/<Filter>/,/<\/Filter>/s/test/lookup/' input.xml > input_1.xml
```

below is my input.xml file:

```
<NikuDataBus
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./src/webroot/WEB-INF/xog/xsd/nikuxog_entity.xsd">
    <Header version="14.2" action="read" objectType="contentPack" externalSource="NIKU"/>
    <LookupQuery>
        <Filter name="code" criteria="EQUALS">test</Filter>
    </LookupQuery>
</NikuDataBus>
```

Comment: please click [edit] and add the sample input to question.. after adding the sample, select them and use the `{}` button or `ctrl+k` to format the data for better viewing... also, use parsers like xmlstarlet instead of sed for editing xml data

Comment: can you help me with xmlstarlet sample to edit the xml. I am new to shell scripting

Answer (score 7):

Parsing `XML` with a non-syntax aware tool like `sed` is a bad idea. The solution would break is there is a slightest change in the `XML` formatting. Use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) which is syntax aware tool for editing files.

Since your file is syntactically valid also, it is pretty straightforward to solve your problem. Just do

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//NikuDataBus/LookupQuery/Filter' --value 'lookup' input.xml
```

To make the edit of the file in-place just like `sed -i`, use the `-L` flag to the solution *if* your version supports it or use a temporary file (`> temp && mv temp input.xml`)

```
xmlstarlet edit -L --update '//NikuDataBus/LookupQuery/Filter' --value 'lookup' input.xml
```

Or you could go one step further and do the replace *only* if the `Filter` tag contains `test` which you can do as

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//NikuDataBus/LookupQuery/Filter[contains(.,"test")]' --value 'lookup' input.xml
```

Tested on Centos 7 on the following version.

```
$ xmlstarlet --version
compiled against libxml2 2.9.1, linked with 20901
compiled against libxslt 1.1.28, linked with 10128
```

Thanks to one of the useful comments from ever `Perl` expert - [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep), you could see the list of paths that could be traversed on which you can apply operations with `xmlstarlet`

```
$ xmlstarlet el input.xml
NikuDataBus
NikuDataBus/Header
NikuDataBus/LookupQuery
NikuDataBus/LookupQuery/Filter
```

Comment: what if I want to edit the xml using shell script only. I dont have permissions to use xmlstarlet. My requirement is to update the <Filter>  tag value based on the user input .

Comment: @priyanka: This is the ideal way to your problem. If you can't use `xmlstarlet`, good luck using other tools to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with everything Inian said, but you should also note that your regular expression is incorrect: your sample data does not contain the string `<Filter>`. Hence, you need to use a different pattern, like:

```
 sed '/<Filter/,/<\/Filter>/s/test/lookup/' ...
```

But, again, you shouldn't.

Comment: you mean in the syntax I have to add whole '<Filter name="code" criteria="EQUALS">' thing ?

Comment: It worked. Thanks . May I know why I should not use this ?

Comment: Because it is too brittle. The basic building block of `sed` is a line, and the basic building block of XML is a node. You want to change data within a node. In your example, this node happens to be neatly isolated on a single line, but in general, this cannot be taken for granted.